# Is there a tracing debugger like `dbg` available for Haskell or OCaml?

Tags: haskell, erlang, ocaml, dbg

Is there a tracing debugger like `dbg` available for Haskell or OCaml?

Very informally, it's printf-style debugging only better, completely configurable at runtime. In essence, the user can register a trace handler when a system is running, which will be called on each action from a set of actions supported by the runtime (e.g. on each function call/return, on each message sent/received etc.). Such a handler may log every operation, which gives a nice sequence of all the steps happening in (part of) the system.

This mechanism can be used for logging/debugging, profiling certain parts of the system, but in many cases just for discovering how a new (unknown to the programmer) system works.

Comment: `ocamldebug` doesn't have the trace style debugging you're talking about, but does support breakpoints and time-travel. There is also profiling support from additional tools / flags.

Comment: Although not a debugger per se, the OCaml top-level has `#trace` and `#install_printer` which can go a long way.

Answer (score 4):

For Haskell, GHCi provides a simple imperative style debugger. Look it's [documentation](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/ghci-debugger.html) to find more details about it. Some of its feature are

- Ability to set a breakpoint
- Stepping through execution
- Inspecting local variables
- Treating Exceptions as breakpoints
- Typing in any code to execute it immediately

Comment: Indeed. For the record, I find GHCi's ability to run any code I like from within scope with whatever arguments I like _far_ more useful than any set of traditional debugging tools.

Comment: @AndrewC That's fine. :) In fact I only use `ghci` for the feature you listed on.

Comment: GHCi also has the `:trace` command, which is probably the most relevant feature for *this* question. (Although it might be less powerful than what erszcz is looking for and only works starting from a breakpoint.)